# Not able to update base_site.html for Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

I am following Django 1.7 tutorial, I need to update the default heading of the Django admin site, by using customized base_site.html. However for some issues, I am not able to do it. I went through the similar questions on stackoverflow but could not resolve my issue, So I am posting it.

I have Django 1.7 installed.

My base_site.html is at path : C:\Users\sanjiv\Google Drive\Documents\II-Sem\Python_Practice\mysite\templates\admin

I updated Template_loader variable, however I read tht having this variable  in your settings.py is optional for Django 1.7

My settings.py:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = '####################'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/sanjiv/Google Drive/Documents/II-Sem/Python_Practice/mysite/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your templates folder, create another folder and name it "admin", then put your "base_site.html" there. Somehow like this:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'TITLE HERE' %}{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}

{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}


<h3 id="site-name">{% trans 'TITLE HERE' %}</h3>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ohh..my mistake.. I had /admin folder inside my templates folder, but didn't update in the program.  I have updated the program but still the issue remains. I have also commented the  TEMPLATE_LOADERS .    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/sanjiv/Google Drive/Documents/II-Sem/Python_Practice/mysite/templates/admin',
)

Comment: Try using this in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`

Comment: I used TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')] but still not able to solve the issue. What  else can be wrong here?

Comment: I was able to solve this issue..I had to make some changes in the base_site.html file. Thanks for your response. Just to clarify either one of these works:

Comment: TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/sanjiv/Google Drive/Documents/II-Sem/Python_Practice/mysite/templates/',
)
OR
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')]